# How Would You Categorize This Beer?

Tags: judging, competition

[image: Take Pride In Your Beer]

I created a beer called [Rye of the Hurricane II](http://midnighthourbrewery.blogspot.com/search/label/rye) and would like to enter it in competitions. Problem is, I am not sure it fits in a [BCJP category](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/catdex.php). Where would you enter this?

It is too dark for American Rye (6D), and *may* be out of category for Roggenbier (15D).

It has great body and plum/raisin maltiness. While it is full-bodied the beer is not heavy. Traditional British hops give it a earthy, muddied bitterness leading into a spicy rye and Hallertau kick. The finish is peppery, slightly sweet and just a little thick on the tongue.

This is the latest version:

### 10 Gallons

- OG: 1.050
- IBU: ~21

### Fermentables

- 15 lbs Maris Otter
- 4 lbs Rye malt
- 2 lbs Munich Malt
- 2 lbs Crystal 120ºL

Mash at 149ºF for 20 minutes. Raise temperature to 160º for 40 minutes

### Hops

60 Minute boil

- 2 oz Mt Hood FWH
- 1 oz East Kent Goldings 30 minutes
- 1 oz Hallertau 10 minutes
- 1 oz Hallertau 5 minutes

Irish Moss 15 minutes

### Fermentation

Ferment with WYeast 1318 London Ale Yeast III at 68ºF for 28 days

### Serving

Medium Carbonation

[image: Ingredients]

Comment: I would use BJCP category "812 - Looks Yummy".  Seriously though, I have no idea.  But it does look awesome.

Comment: Didn't see that category on the entry form.  Gotta say: it is awesome. Started off 75% Maris Otter, 20% rye, 5% Munich - which was so-so. The above recipe is great. Next I'm adding some Special B for 62.5% Maris Otter, 16.5% rye, 8% Munich, 8% Crystal 120L, 4% Special B. That might not be enough rye though.

Comment: This is indeed a great question.  I love it just because of the beer porn pictures.  Much thanks.

Comment: I'm totally making this at some point.

Comment: I'm very interested in making this. Is this where you'll keep the latest version?

Comment: I update it over on Hopville: http://hopville.com/brewer/brundage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe an English Pale ale?  Think more about the hop profile and count the rye as a bonus.  There's also no rule that says you can't enter the same beer in multiple categories.  Try a couple of different ones and see where it scores well.

Answer (score 1):

If the rye is at all noticeable, you'll need to enter it as a specialty beer.  If you read the style guidelines, rye is not to style for any pale ale or IPA.  It's definitely not an Am. rye or roggenbier.  The best way to determine which category to enter a beer in is to sit down and drink some while you read the guidelines for the style you're thinking of.  Try to taste what the guidelines describe.  Then enter it in the category it tastes like, despite what you thought you were making when you brewed it.